# @media queries issues

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm modifying someone else's css and I try to make the page responsive with implementing @media query. 
I implemented:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px),
screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {}
```

which works fine, but when I implement 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){} it seems it's not working.

OR - on chrome and opera seems to work quite ok, but not on FF: on FF the page is cutted at the right end, no scroller and I really don't know why. It doesn't change even if I use positon:relative, I checke - I don't have any of 'overflow:hidden'.

And the other thing - for media query it is suggested to use min-width - but if I use min-width, then only the lowest (for example min-width:600) is applied.

I think I missed something here ... any suggestions? I would really appreciated them .. as I'm very keen on responsive web design.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a clean way to test if your `@media` queries are working or not:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:860px) {
    body {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color:orange;
    }
}
```

Your background should be `black` by default, `red` if if the min-width of your screen is 1024 pixels, `yellow` if it falls below 860px, and `orange` if it falls down to 600px.

So make sure that there are no conflicting media queries in your stylesheet.

http://jsfiddle.net/crUVv/show/

Comment: thanks, Andres ... I'm testing with firebug. The point is that does not work in FF, only in Opera and Chrome. the other thing are scrollbars which appear when the page is larger than the viewport - I cannot make it appear. the page is cut-off. (in FF is working all, except for max-width 600px)

Comment: @AngelM. The demo i provided is working fine for me for all `@media` queries in firefox (3.6.17), can you provide a link to your site so we can take a look? I'm sure there has to be some conflicting `@media` queries somewhere.

Comment: your test was very useful for me ... but unfortunatelly - even this is not working in my FF v.9 and I really don't know why .. I would give you the link, but I'm in the middle of major changes right now - I decided to do it my way and then will see. If you'll be still willing I'd appreaciate. thanks

Answer (score 5):

This may not be your actual problem, but I think worth pointing out that when testing responsiveness to media queries for small viewport sizes, make sure all the browser window adornments are not getting in the way.

I had a "problem" like this recently. At first I thought Firefox media queries were at fault, until I checked and realised that it was the browser nav bar size stopping me from actually resizing below my min-width value.

i.e. it wasn't the page at fault - there was just  too much stuff in the nav bar that prevented the browser from resizing below a certain point. This also explained why the behaviour *seemed* different in different browsers

Turn off the browser nav bar and it worked fine. Doh!